# Lock screen shortcuts cannot be changed

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

When my mobile had 4.1 version of Android, I could go to Security -> Lock screen -> Shortcuts to change the shortcuts. But, after Android 4.3 update, I am unable to find a way to change the shortcuts on the lock screen. Could you guide me through how I can achieve this?

I tried Settings -> My Device -> Lock Screen, but there is no Shortcuts button there.

See the screenshot below:

[image: settings]
<sup>(click image for larger version)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What kind of security are you using on your phone? If you are using Swipe to Unlock (no pin) you should be able to see the shortcuts.

If you have some other sort of security, the lockscreen changes for Android 4.3 and TouchWiz integration have made some of these features disappear.

There is a pretty good discussion about it [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/319298-lock-screen-widgets-note-3-missing.html).

Comment: Sorry about the "-1". My touchpad is very sensitive and when I noticed it was too late to undo the vote... :(

Comment: @AntoineAubry - You know you can just click on the upvote button and it'll go away.

Comment: I can't. After some time the vote becomes locked unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @AntoineAubry I've edited the answer now (I only added a space, no content modified) so that you can undo the -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

i also encounter this issue and i find a fix to it. i have galaxy S3 rooted so i don't knew if it'll work on unrooted devices, but you can try.

open with any file manager (i'm using ES) the folder system > go to folder 'csc' > then find the file customer.xml and rename it to customer.xml.bak.

Reboot the device and go to Lockscreen. you will find lost shortcut slide.

thanks to ValenteLform xda-developers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I don't use a rooted phone, but gave your +1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings>my device>lock screen>screen lock

Select swipe

Turn "Shortcuts" on

Click the word "Shortcuts" and your lock screen shortcuts will appear; edit as you desire.

Change your screen lock back to your desired security setting and the new shortcuts will stay in place.

I just got my S3 and apparently Android 4.3 doesn't allow access to shortcuts when phone is locked (makes sense I guess, why lock something but allow access to parts of it?), but you can change the "Secured lock time" which will give you time to use those chosen apps from the lock screen.

Comment: Why don't I see 'shortcuts' under Lock screen? I enabled swipe, but can only edit widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Touch apps>widgets>locate settings and touch and hold to move it to phone screen then select lock screen.  You will now see all options to make changes to your lock screen

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but I came across this issue and thought I'd answer in case someone still has this problem.

I'm running Android v4.4 and the shortcuts are hidden.But before that,
*Settings* → *My device* → *Lock screen* → *Set screen lock* to *Swipe*
Now change the shortcuts setting below that from camera to custom and new option will appear to edit shortcuts.  I think these shortcuts will still work even if you decide to add a password later.

For widgets make sure multiple widgets is checked on this screen as well then on the lock screen.
You simply swipe right on the clock widget which is there by-default then click on *edit* in the lower right corner of the new screen to edit which widget appears on that page.  It's an inconvenient 1 widget per page, however if you wish to change the default lock screen clock to another widget you can then rearrange the pages by long pressing and moving that page/widget to the far right.